# Position button on background images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a grid template for a website. I would also like to have a css class templates for position a button. The button class templates should have the following placements:

- Top left corner
- Top right corner
- Center
- Left bottom corner
- Right bottom corner

I am not quite sure how I need to make the CSS for this? The image is used as a background-image.

I hope somebody help me with this question?

[Link to the code on Online Bootstrap Editor](https://www.bootply.com/Vj3jzFoC9r)

```css
<style>

.d-flex {
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: flex!important
}

.d-inline-flex {
    display: -ms-inline-flexbox!important;
    display: inline-flex!important
}
.flex-wrap {
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap!important;
    flex-wrap: wrap!important
}
.bg-img {
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; }

/* CTA Buttons */

.btn-top-left {

}

.btn-top-right {
  
}

.btn-center {

}

.btn-bottom-left {
  
}

.btn-bottom-right {
  
}


/* :: Set overlay over image and placement of text */
.single-welcome-post {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1; }
  .single-welcome-post::after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    content: '';
    z-index: 5; }
  .single-welcome-post .welcome-post-content {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 50px; }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
      .single-welcome-post .welcome-post-content {
        left: 20px;
        bottom: 20px;
        right: 20px; } }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .single-welcome-post .welcome-post-content {
        left: 15px;
        bottom: 15px;
        right: 15px; } }
  .single-welcome-post.style-2 {
    height: 645px; }
 

 

.hero-area {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #edf1f4;
  padding: 5px; }
  .hero-area .hero-single-section {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    width: 50%; }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .hero-area .hero-single-section {
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%; } }
  .hero-area .item1 {
    height: 700px;
    margin: 5px; }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
      .hero-area .item1 {
        height: 600px; } }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
      .hero-area .item1 {
        height: 500px; } }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .hero-area .item1 {
        height: 350px; } }
  .hero-area .item2 {
    height: 340px;
    margin: 5px; }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
      .hero-area .item2 {
        height: 290px; } }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
      .hero-area .item2 {
        height: 240px; } }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .hero-area .item2 {
        height: 200px; } }
  .hero-area .item3 {
    height: 350px;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px);
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px);
    max-width: calc(50% - 10px);
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    margin: 5px; }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
      .hero-area .item3 {
        height: 300px; } }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
      .hero-area .item3 {
        height: 250px; } }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .hero-area .item3 {
        height: 200px; } }
  .hero-area .item4 {
    height: 350px;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px);
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px);
    max-width: calc(50% - 10px);
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    margin: 5px; }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
      .hero-area .item4 {
        height: 300px; } }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
      .hero-area .item4 {
        height: 250px; } }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .hero-area .item4 {
        height: 200px; } }



.single-blog-post {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1; }
  .single-blog-post .blog-thumb {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; }
    .single-blog-post .blog-thumb img {
      width: 100%; }
  .single-blog-post .blog-content .post-tag {
    color: #a6a6a6;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 5px; }
    .single-blog-post .blog-content .post-tag:hover, .single-blog-post .blog-content .post-tag:focus {
      color: #ff1662; }

    /* Set font-size */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .single-blog-post .blog-content .post-tag {
        font-size: 10px; } }
  .single-blog-post .blog-content .post-title {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: block;
    color: #282828;
    margin-bottom: 10px; }
    
  

    /* Align text */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .single-blog-post .blog-content .post-title {
        font-size: 16px; } }
    .single-blog-post .blog-content .post-title:hover, .single-blog-post .blog-content .post-title:focus {
      color: #ff1662; }
  .single-blog-post .blog-content .post-meta {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex; }

    /* Set space between text elements*/
    .single-blog-post .blog-content .post-meta a {
      color: #ffffff;
      margin-right: 15px;
      font-size: 11px;
      line-height: 1;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-align: end;
      -ms-flex-align: end;
      -ms-grid-row-align: flex-end;
      align-items: flex-end; }
    

      /* Set color and placement on text*/
      @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .single-blog-post .blog-content .post-meta a {
          font-size: 8px;
          margin-right: 5px; } }
      .single-blog-post .blog-content .post-meta a img {
        margin-right: 10px; }
      .single-blog-post .blog-content .post-meta a:last-child {
        margin-right: 0; }
      .single-blog-post .blog-content .post-meta a:hover, .single-blog-post .blog-content .post-meta a:focus {
        color: #ff1662; }
  .single-blog-post.white .blog-content .post-title,
  .single-blog-post.white .blog-content .post-tag,
  .single-blog-post.white .blog-content .post-meta a {
    color: #ffffff; }
    .single-blog-post.white .blog-content .post-title:hover, .single-blog-post.white .blog-content .post-title:focus,
    .single-blog-post.white .blog-content .post-tag:hover,
    .single-blog-post.white .blog-content .post-tag:focus,
    .single-blog-post.white .blog-content .post-meta a:hover,
    .single-blog-post.white .blog-content .post-meta a:focus {
      color: #008ebe; }
  .single-blog-post.style2 .blog-content .post-title {
    font-size: 24px; }
</style>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="hero-area d-flex flex-wrap">

        <div class="hero-single-section">
            <!-- Single Welcome Post -->
            <div class="single-welcome-post bg-img item1" style="background-image: url(http://vouzalis.dk/stack/1.jpg);">
                <!-- Content -->
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aNNYEUARAk" class="video-play-btn"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
                <!-- Content -->
                <div class="welcome-post-content">
                    <!-- Single Blog Post -->
                    <div class="single-blog-post white">
                        <div class="blog-content">
                            <a href="#" class="post-tag">Featured</a>
                            <a href="#" class="post-title">Watch a tiny cat taking a bath</a>
                            <div class="post-meta">
                                <a href="#">Here is a text about the picture</a>
                            </div>
                            <button href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-center">Read More</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="hero-single-section">
            <!-- Single Welcome Post -->
            <div class="single-welcome-post bg-img item2" style="background-image: url(http://vouzalis.dk/stack/2.jpg);">
                <!-- Content -->
                
            </div>

            <div class="hero-second-section d-flex flex-wrap">
                <!-- Single Welcome Post -->
                <div class="single-welcome-post bg-img item3" style="background-image: url(http://vouzalis.dk/stack/3.jpg);">
                    <!-- Content -->
                    
                </div>

                <!-- Single Welcome Post -->
                <div class="single-welcome-post bg-img item4" style="background-image: url(http://vouzalis.dk/stack/4.jpg);">
                    <!-- Content -->
                    <div class="welcome-post-content">
                        <!-- Single Blog Post -->
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: position:absolute then top/left/right/bottom ?

Comment: Is that also gonna make the buttons responsive? Is it fx: left: 10%? The problems is also the the grid is in a flexbox, so I am not quite sure where in the code the button should be?

Comment: there are actually 2 ways here either you make the image a background image for a div with relative position inside and then add another div inside of it to position it as you want with positionabsolute attribute